# Using numpy in sklearn FunctionTransformer inside pipeline

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, dill

I'm training a regression model and inside my pipeline I have something like this:

```
best_pipeline = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        (
            "features",
            ColumnTransformer(
                transformers=[
                    (
                        "area",
                        make_pipeline(
                            impute.SimpleImputer(),
                            pr.FunctionTransformer(lambda x: np.log1p(x)),
                            StandardScaler(),
                        ),
                        ["area"],
                    )
                ]
            ),
        ),
        (
            "regressor",
            TransformedTargetRegressor(
                regressor=model,
                transformer=PowerTransformer(method='box-cox')
            ),
        ),
    ]
)
```

There are obviously more features but the code will be too long. So I train the model and if I predict in the same script everything is fine. I store the model using dill and then try to use it in another python file.

In this other file I load the model and try this:

```
import numpy as np
df['prediction'] = self.model.predict(df)
```

And internally, when it tries to do the `transform` it returns:

```
NameError: name 'np' is not defined
```

Comment: I think this is probably a dill issue - see https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/issues/126.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use third-party library functions by simply passing the name of the function as a `func` argument:

```
import numpy

transformer = FunctionTransformer(numpy.log1p)
```

There is no need for lambdas or custom wrapper classes. Also, the above solution is persistable in plain pickle data format.

When porting objects between different environments, then it's probably a good idea to use canonical module names. Hence `numpy.log1p` instead of `np.log1p`.

Comment: You are right thank you very much! It worked like that. I would like to fully understand it, do you know why using `numpy` works but `np` doesn't?

Comment: The likely explanation is that `numpy` is a canonical module name, whereas `np` is a local module name alias (eg. derived via `import numpy as np`), which may or may not exist in other environments.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to fix it, although there might be a better approach.

I create a class encapsulating the numpy function

```
class LogTransformer(pr.FunctionTransformer):
    
    def transform(self, X):
        import numpy as np

        return np.log1p(X)
```

Then when I create the pipeline:

```
 make_pipeline(
      impute.SimpleImputer(),
      LogTransformer(),
      StandardScaler(),
 ),
```

Any other approaches are welcomed

Comment: This is bad advice in the given situation.

Comment: Why this is a bad approach? Imagine I would like to perform more scaling to the variable, let's say I would also like to round the feature, is it not a good idea to create a new class inheriting from `FunctionTransformer` ?

Comment: It's over-complicated when the target function is a Numpy universal function (ufunc). However, it may be an appropriate solution when dealing with more complex feature engineerings tasks.

Comment: For more complex tasks (many Numpy ufuncs combined) it's probably a better idea to inherit directly from `sklearn.base.TransformerMixin` not `sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer`. The reason is that FunctionTransformer promises to implement inverse transformations and stuff that your complex transformer probably cannot do, or doesn't care about. So, don't promise more than you can deliver.